# Why does sql server do a scan on joins when there are no records in source table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The idea of the below query is to use the CTE to get the primary key of all rows in [Archive].[tia_tia_object] that meet the filter.

The execution time for the query within the CTE is 0 seconds.

The second part is supposed to do joins on other tables, to filter the data some more, but only if there are any rows returned in the CTE. This was the only way I could get the SQL server to use the correct indexes.

Why does it spend time (see execution plan) looking in TIA_TIA_AGREEMENT_LINE and TIA_TIA_OBJECT, when CTE returns 0 rows?

```
WITH cte_vehicle 
     AS (SELECT O.[Seq_no], 
                O.Object_No 
         FROM   [Archive].[tia_tia_object] O 
         WHERE  O.RECORD_TIMESTAMP > 
            (SELECT LastLoadTimeStamp FROM staging.Ufngetlastloadtimestamp('Staging.CoveredObject')) 
            AND O.[Meta_iscurrent] = 1 
            AND O.OBJECT_TYPE IN ( 'BIO01', 'CAO01', 'DKV', 'GFO01', 
                                   'KMA', 'KNO01', 'MCO01', 'VEO01', 
                                   'SVO01', 'AUO01' )) 
SELECT O.[Seq_no]                      AS [Bkey_CoveredObject], 
       Cast(O.[Agr_Line_No] AS BIGINT) AS [Agr_Line_No], 
       O.[Cover_Start_Date]            AS [CoverageFrom], 
       O.[Cover_End_Date]              AS [CoverageTo], 
       O.[Timestamp]                   AS [TIMESTAMP], 
       O.[Record_Timestamp]            AS [RECORD_TIMESTAMP], 
       O.[Newest]                      AS [Newest], 
       O.LOCATION_ID                   AS LocationNo, 
       O.[Cust_no], 
       O.[N01] 
FROM   cte_vehicle AS T 
       INNER JOIN [Archive].[tia_tia_object] O 
               ON t.Object_No = O.Object_No 
                  AND t.Seq_No = O.Seq_No 
       INNER JOIN [Archive].[tia_tia_agreement_line] AL 
               ON O.Agr_line_no = AL.Agr_line_no 
       INNER JOIN [Archive].[tia_tia_policy] P
                ON AL.Policy_no = P.Policy_no 
WHERE  P.[Transaction_type] <> 'D'
```

Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: A CTE is expanded inline into the query as if it was a subquery, and the query is in turn optimized as a whole, meaning the conditions used in `JOIN` and `WHERE` can get shifted around depending on what the optimizer considers prudent. Don't make the mistake of thinking the CTE happens "first", or even that the joins happen in order (the latter can be forced with a query hint, though that's rarely necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What would be a better way to have the logic in the CTE happen first? Have a secondary table that I insert the results to, and then select from that instead of the CTE?

Comment: Using an intermediate temp table is the standard approach if you know that the query will usually return few to no rows, yes -- the optimizer will have statistics for the actual data in that case. Be careful with that, though, because it obviously backfires if the query returns a lot of data and you force the optimizer to materialize everything (and write it to disk!), without a chance of filtering it up front through clever condition reshuffling. A join on few (or *no*) rows usually takes few resources; carefully consider if you really *have* to optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it still needs to check and look for records. Even if there are no records in that table, it doesn't know that until it actually checks.

Much like if someone gives you a sealed box, you don't know it's empty or not till you open it.

Comment: But the CTE returns no records so what is it looking for?

Comment: @Kenci - SQL Server is building a hash table to support the join operation. Whilst it's doing that and if it has some idle time, would you prefer it did *nothing* or it started some (potentially) expensive I/O, thus *hiding* some of the I/O overheads in the (far more probable, overall) case when it will need to perform some joining?